# C# Selenium how to scroll a scrollable div, not the entire webpage without using pageup/pgdn

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, selenium

I'm trying to scroll a div that loads rows everytime I reach the bottom of the scrollbar. Now I am doing this by "scrolling" the scrollbar of the div using PgUp and PgDn but I encountered a problem where a specific div is not accepting pgup/pgdown/home/end. How do I drag and drop the scrollbar using C# and Selenium?

This is my code for pgup and pgdn:

```
private void ScrollTable(int scrollcount, string pageDirection, string delay)
                {
                    Actions actions = new Actions(DlkEnvironment.AutoDriver);
                    actions.MoveToElement(mTableElement);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= scrollcount; i++)
                    {
                       //if loading is not displayed/visible,
                       IsLoadingScreenIsDisplayed(delay);
                       //execute after waiting
                       switch (pageDirection.ToLower())
                       {
                           case "up":
                               actions.Click().SendKeys(Keys.PageUp).Perform();
                               break;
                           case "down":
                               actions.Click().SendKeys(Keys.PageDown).Perform();
                               break;
                           default:
                               throw new Exception("Invalid direction");
                       }   
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using JavaScript, scrollTop function. use the scrollTop function to your element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SendKeys` without sending it to specific element

```
private void ScrollTable(int scrollcount, string pageDirection, string delay)
{
    Actions actions = new Actions(DlkEnvironment.AutoDriver);

    for (int i = 1; i <= scrollcount; i++)
    {
        //if loading is not displayed/visible,
        IsLoadingScreenIsDisplayed(delay);
        //execute after waiting
        switch (pageDirection.ToLower())
        {
            case "up":
                actions.SendKeys(Keys.PageUp).Perform();
                break;
            case "down":
                actions.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown).Perform();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid direction");
        }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: the div is not accepting pgUp/pgDn keys for some reason,